# SQL Server management studio Linked Server access from another computer

Tags: mysql, database, server, ssms

I have a work assignment that consists of linking two databases on two different computers through SQL Server Management Studio. Basically, both databases have to transmit the same data to a centralized SCADA from some machines that have different tasks.

What I am trying to do is making this connection through Linked Servers. I managed to set up the OCBD server on the first machine with no problems at all. After that I started setting up the connection on the second machine so that they could communicate. I am getting an array of problems but the most common is the one at the bottom.

I have searched plenty of pages for a solution but everyone suggests solutions that have no affect on my project, so i was wondering id anyone knows what is wrong with my settings. If it's not my settings, then could it be some Firewall setting or something along the lines of that.

[My settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lELi.png)

[My settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1API.png)

[My settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDWic.png)

[This is the error I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpC09.png)